# Using documentID redirection to a infopath form open in infopath filler not in browser

Tags: infopath

I would like to use the Document ID feature to redirect user to a InfoPath form. However, after the redirection, the form try to open in a InfoPath filler rather than in web browser. It works fine in Firefox but not in IE.I configured the document library settings to open the form in web browser. If I click the document in the form library directly , it will work and here is url

http://ybbestSiteCollection/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/TestLiability/bb-2011-02-25-Renewal-cc.xml&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fgr026015%2Dsp1%2FTestLiability%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1

If I use the document ID redirection using

http://ybbestSiteCollection/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=QAN7VXTX3TT5-1-1

It will redirect me to

http://ybbestSiteCollection/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/TestLiability/bb-2011-02-25-Renewal-cc.xml**&DefaultItemOpen=1**

Can I change the redirection logic to redirect to

http://ybbestSiteCollection/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/TestLiability/bb-2011-02-25-Renewal-cc.xml**&OpenIn=Browser**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that if the URL points to the InfoPath XML file it will try to open it in the InfoPath client if it can. The library setting to open in the browser just affects the link you get in the libarary, not the Document ID redirect URL.

It probably "works" in Firefox because that browser doesn't understand the InfoPath client integration ActiveX control (or whatever it uses in IE).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers on Opening InfoPath forms in SharePoint:

http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Vardhaman/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=10